# How can I get Eyeglass to correctly discover my node_modules with gulp-sass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gulp, gulp-sass, node-sass, eyeglass

Trying to clean up my Rails asset pipeline with gulp. Tired of adding every npm package scss/css file to includePaths explicitly. I've searched thoroughly and read the docs, but I'm still having trouble getting [Eyeglass](https://github.com/sass-eyeglass/eyeglass) to find my node_modules.

Here's the setup I have so far:

```
var sassPaths = [
'./app/assets/stylesheets/*',
publicAssets + '/stylesheets',
'./node_modules/magic.css/1.1.0/',
'./node_modules/colors.css/sass/'
],
sassOptions = {
indentedSyntax: true,
sourceComments: true,
errLogToConsole: true,
includePaths: sassPaths,
eyeglass: {
  enableImportOnce: false,
  buildDir: publicAssets + '/stylesheets',
  assets: {
    // prefix to give assets for their output url.
    httpPrefix: "assets",

    installer: function(assetFile, assetUri, oldInstaller, cb) {
      // oldInstaller is the standard eyeglass installer in this case.
      // We proxy to it for logging purposes.
      oldInstaller(assetFile, assetUri, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error installing '" + assetFile + "': " + err.toString());
        } else {
          console.log("Installed Asset '" + assetFile + "' => '" + result + "'");
        }
        cb(err, result);
      });
    },

    // Add assets except for js and sass files
    // The url passed to asset-url should be
    // relative to the assets directory specified.
    sources: [{
        directory: './node_modules/',
        pattern: [
          '**/dist/*',
          '**/dist/{scss,sass,css}/*',
          '**/{scss,sass,css}/*',
          '**/*.{scss, sass, css}',
          '**/{scss,sass,css}/*'
        ],
        globOpts: { ignore: ["**/*.js"], root: '.', }
      }]
    },
  importer: function(uri, prev, done) {
    done(sass.compiler.types.NULL);
  }
}
},
 eyeglass = new Eyeglass(sassOptions);

  console.log(eyeglass.modules);
  console.log(eyeglass.assets.assetPath);

stream = gulp.src(sassSource)
.pipe(sourceMaps.init())
.pipe(sass(eyeglass.options).on("error", sass.logError))
.pipe(postcss([lost(), autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] }) ]));
```

I'm trying to point Eyeglass to the `'./node_modules'` path and use the pattern array to have it properly parse the installed packages for css/scss to import. As I look over the docs, it doesn't really seem necessary to even have to guide it with patterns, but that it'll know where to look once you point it to the right directory.

Is there a simple way to add all my `--save-dev` modules to eyeglass?

Comment: Are you on windows or linux?

Comment: I am on Mac, never solved this.

Comment: It now works on windows, since version 0.9